# Gui SwingWorker ... not updating everything before repaint

Tags: user-interface, swingworker

My gui is a 50x50 GridLayout that updates using the SwingWorker.

Each grid in the GridLayout has a GridGraphic component which has a specific intensity.
Default intensity = 0, which is just a black component.  If intensity = 5, then the grid appears black with a yellow dot.

When the Step button is pushed, the StepManager is supposed to go through all the grids and update their intensity and then repaint everything at once, but the StepManager stops executing after the first GridGraphic that has a alue with an intensity = 5.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class Gui extends JFrame{

    private JPanel buttonPanel, populationPanel, velocityPanel, gridPanel;
    private JButton setupButton, stepButton, goButton;
    private JLabel populationNameLabel, velocityNameLabel, populationSliderValueLabel, velocitySliderValueLabel;
    private JSlider populationSlider, velocitySlider;
    private GridGraphic [] [] gridGraphic;
    private int agents = 125;
    private int velocity = 500;
    private boolean resetGrid;
    private StepManager step;


    public Gui() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();


        //Set up JButtons
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        setupButton = new JButton("Setup");
        stepButton = new JButton("Step");
        goButton = new JButton("Go");

        buttonPanel.add(setupButton);
        buttonPanel.add(stepButton);
        buttonPanel.add(goButton);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(buttonPanel, c);




    public GridGraphic getGridGraphic(int n1, int n2){
        return gridGraphic[n1][n2];
    }


    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what happens is that step is executed in a separate thread, so when you call execute method on it, it starts executing in a separate thread, which may finish executing way after you call the repaint method. What you want is to call repaint after the worker is finished with its task. Look into SwingWorker's done() method.

Comment: SwingWorker's finished() method?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get some sort of exception?

In your code

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            if(grid[i][j].getIntensity()==5){
                grid[i][j].setDefault();
                grid[i-1][j-1].setAgent();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because you may be accessing grid[-1][-1] if i or j are 0 and grid[i][0] and/or grid[0][j] have an intensity of 5.

---

Edit: Another thing. It seems you are repainting your GUI only once, after executing the SwingWorker. But, the SwingWorker is a thread, so the repaint will be executed immediately after the worker started, not after it's finished. Try calling repaint in your done method.

Comment: everything compiles and runs without any runtime errors.  strange huh. Why does the gui repaints after the first grid with intensity = 5 that it encounters, instead of updating all grids and then repainting

Comment: Since you are setting the array objects randomly, you might run into an AIOOBE sooner or later. You could print i and j on every loop iteration to see if the worker really stops (I can't see why it should). It may also be a repaint problem, see my edit.